# Not able to execute query in esper

Tags: java, esper

The code I have written to execute query is as follows:

```
EPServiceProvider cep = EPServiceProviderManager.getProvider("EventChannelling",config);
EPRuntime rt=cep.getEPRuntime();            
EPServiceProvider cep1 = EPServiceProviderManager.getDefaultProvider(config);
String query = "create table CustomerRules ( C_ID String primary key, E_Type int primary key, Rule int )";
rt.executeQuery(query);
```

But I am getting the following error:

> Exception in thread "main"
>   com.espertech.esper.client.EPStatementException: Error executing
>   statement: 0 [create table CustomerRules ( C_ID String primary key,
>   E_Type int primary key, Rule int )]   at
>   com.espertech.esper.core.service.EPRuntimeImpl.getExecuteMethod(EPRuntimeImpl.java:1671)
>     at
>   com.espertech.esper.core.service.EPRuntimeImpl.executeQueryInternal(EPRuntimeImpl.java:1552)
>     at
>   com.espertech.esper.core.service.EPRuntimeImpl.executeQuery(EPRuntimeImpl.java:1526)
>     at Example.main(Example.java:148)

Can someone tell me the reason for this error?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Configuration config = new Configuration();

//TODO Configure...

EPServiceProvider epService = EPServiceProviderManager.getDefaultProvider(config);

Module module = epService.getEPAdministrator().getDeploymentAdmin().parse("create table CustomerRules (C_ID String primary key, E_Type int primary key, Rule int);");

epService.getEPAdministrator().getDeploymentAdmin().deploy(module, null);

epService.getEPRuntime().executeQuery("insert into CustomerRules(C_ID, E_Type, Rule) values ('1', 1, 1)");
```

Let me know if it worked!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to execute a create statement with the EPRuntime, which is used for on demand queries. Try this instead:

```
    Configuration config = new Configuration();
    config.addEventType("Event", new String[] {"C_ID", "E_Type", "Rule"}, new Object[] {String.class, Integer.class, Integer.class});

    EPServiceProvider cep = EPServiceProviderManager.getProvider("EventChannelling",config);
EPRuntime rt=cep.getEPRuntime();
        String query = "create table CustomerRules ( C_ID String primary key, E_Type int primary key, Rule int )";
    cep.getEPAdministrator().createEPL(query);
    cep.getEPAdministrator().createEPL("insert into CustomerRules select C_ID, E_Type, Rule from Event");
cep.getEPRuntime().getEventSender("Event").sendEvent(new Object[]{"Prueba", 100, 100});
    System.out.println(rt.executeQuery("select * from CustomerRules").getArray()[0].get("C_ID"));
```

I compiled this code, I had no complaints from the esper engine and I got the output "Prueba"

Let me know if this was helpful.

Answer (score -1):

Use the `createEPL` method for creating tables. The runtime query API is for querying and not for creating tables.